# How to write a multi export in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to export multiple component but without success.

The code for export is the following:

```
export default props => {
  const validate = (values, props) => {
    let errors = {};

    if (!values.userName) {
      errors.userName = "required";
    }
    if (!values.userEmail) {
      errors.userEmail = "required";
    }
    if (!values.userPhone) {
      errors.userPhone = "required";
    }
    return errors;
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={props.frequency || {}}
      validate={validate}
      render={formikProps => <Recipients {...props} {...formikProps} />}
    />
  );
};

Recipients.propTypes = {
  recipients: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      nome: PropTypes.string,
      email: PropTypes.string,
      phone: PropTypes.string,
      notificationType: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          email: PropTypes.bool,
          SMS: PropTypes.bool
        })
      )
    })
  ),
  changeRecipients: PropTypes.func
};

const styles = theme => ({
  primaryColor: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
});

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Recipients);
```

How i can do this export?
Recipients is my class, withstyles is material ui for theme, and const validate is formik for valite input.

Comment: You can't export more than one thing as `default`--what would the default be?

Comment: if You want to export multiple class or function best practice is using `export {}`

Comment: export default withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(Recipients); is my default

Comment: @mantegnous So is the first function you export.

Answer (score 2):

You can have only one default export, but you can have more named exports.

See the export statement docs:

> There are two different types of export, named and default. You can
>   have multiple named exports per module but only one default export.
>   Each type corresponds to one of the above

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 2):

There can't be more than one `default` export.
But you can have multiple `named exports`, like this

```
export const Recipients = (props) => {
  const validate = (values, props) => {
    let errors = {};

      if (!values.userName) {
        errors.userName = 'required';
      }
      if (!values.userEmail) {
        errors.userEmail = 'required';
      }
      if (!values.userPhone ) {
        errors.userPhone = 'required';
      }
    return errors;
  };

  return(<Formik initialValues={props.frequency || {}}
                 validate={validate}
                 render={(formikProps) => <Recipients {...props} {...formikProps}/>}/>)
};

Recipients.propTypes = {
  recipients: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    nome: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string,
    phone: PropTypes.string,
    notificationType: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      email: PropTypes.bool,
      SMS: PropTypes.bool
    }))
  })),
  changeRecipients: PropTypes.func
};

const styles = theme => ({

  primaryColor: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
});

export const RecipientsWithStyles = withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(Recipients);
```